# Native TextInput is 7 events ahead of JS - try to make your JS faster

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, formik

I have an issue with TextInput in react native

In Profile screen I have Inputs when user update, i send a request to our API, it's work before well!

But now when i update data and open debugger i got this message

> Native TextInput(123456) is 7 events ahead of JS - try to make your JS
>   faster

And for some reason after submitting the data to API 
I got this error

> Exception '*** -[__NSCFConstantString substringToIndex:]: Index 3 out
>   of bounds; string length 0' was thrown while invoking sendRequest on
>   target Networking with params

I use `Formik` and `yup`, For Text input, i use `native-base`

Code snippet

```
state = {
 initialValues: {
      name: '',
      email: '',
      password: '',
      password_confirmation: '',
      age: '',
      gender: '',
      country_id: '',
    },
}

<Formik
                  enablereinitialize
                  validationSchema={formSchema}
                  initialValues={this.state.initialValues}
                  onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
                    this.updateProfile(values);
                    console.log(values), actions.resetForm();
                  }}>
                  {({
                    handleChange,
                    handleBlur,
                    touched,
                    errors,
                    handleSubmit,
                    values,
                    setFieldValue,
                  }) => (
                    <View>
                       .....

                        <Item style={styles.item} floatingLabel>
                        <Label style={styles.formLabel}>password</Label>
                        <Input
                          style={styles.value}
                          rounded
                          secureTextEntry
                          onChangeText={handleChange('password')}
                          onBlur={handleBlur('password')}
                          value={values.password}
                        />
                      </Item>
                      <Text style={styles.errorText}>
                        {touched.password && errors.password}
                      </Text>

                      <Item style={styles.item} floatingLabel>
                        <Label style={styles.formLabel}>
                          confirm password
                        </Label>
                        <Input
                          style={styles.value}
                          rounded
                          secureTextEntry
                          onChangeText={handleChange('password_confirmation')}
                          onBlur={handleBlur('password_confirmation')}
                          value={values.password_confirmation}
                        />
                      </Item>
                      <Text style={[styles.errorText, {paddingBottom: 5}]}>
                        {touched.password_confirmation &&
                          errors.password_confirmation}
                      </Text>
```